# If element has class that ends with do this

Tags: jquery

I know that you can use the code below to check whether an element has a specific class, but what if the class can has different names, but ends the same?

I want to check whether an element has an object that ends with '_hover' (e.g 'blue_hover'), is that possible?

```
if ( $('#element').hasClass("hover") ) {
// do this...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if (/_hover\b/.test($('#element').attr("class"))) {
    // do this...
}
```

Comment: you have a typo: `att` should be `attr`

Comment: This seems like the most effective match. Fixed some more syntax errors for you. Also made a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T7ShC/).

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Does this really work if the element contains of more than one class? Tried it but it didn't match?

Comment: @holyredbeard See the fiddle I posted.